# inner join multi tables with django orm

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 5 models:

```
class Semester(models.Model):
    startAt = models.DateField()
    endAt = models.DateField()
    weeks = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    semesterId = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)

class Subject(models.Model):
    subjectId = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    subjectName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    coefficient = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Class(models.Model):
    classId = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    className = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(to=Subject, on_delete=CASCADE)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(to=Semester, on_delete=CASCADE)

class Schedule(models.Model):
    inClass = models.ForeignKey(to=Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lecturer = models.ForeignKey(to=CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, validators=[validate_lecturer],)
    weeks = ArrayField(
        base_field=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    )
    classroom = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    startAt = models.TimeField()
    endAt = models.TimeField()
    dayOfWeek = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Study(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(to=CustomUser, on_delete=CASCADE, validators=[validate_student])
    inClass = models.ForeignKey(to=Class, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

I want to excute this Postgresql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM study AS st 
INNER JOIN class AS cl ON 
    st."inClass_id" = cl."classId"
INNER JOIN subject as sj on 
    sj."subjectId" = cl.subject_id 
where st.student_id = 4 and cl.semester_id='20211';
```

I'm searching for the ways to perform multiple inner join for a whole day. Please help me!
I'll describe about my models's relationship.

Relationship between:
class and semester is n-1 (a class must take place in a semester)
class and subject is n-1
class and schedule is 1-n (a class can has multiple schedules)
class and study is 1-n (study is a relationship table between student and class)

Comment: A common mistake is to think in terms of JOINs, etc. What is more important if you work with an ORM is: what data you are interested in. JOINing is not an objective itself, it is merely a tool that *can* be used to retrieve certain data.

Comment: Djanog ORM is much capable. It is also secure as you don't need to worry about sql Injections attack. it is better If you give your requirement of query.

Comment: Have you tried [filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)?